# Is there any unique encoding and decoding functions in php?

Tags: php, function, encoding, unique

Here we have a scenario to encode file name and want to decode it while retrieving.
if i encode it with md5 i cant decode it because it is one way hashing and if i encode it with 'base64_encode' then if two files with same name will cause conflict to my data while retrieving.

So i want to know if there in any unique encoding function in PHP to encode and later to decode.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: So you want a two-way encryption algorithm that will give different results for the same input?

Comment: Sigh, MD5 is **not** encoding. Besides it will also return the same hash for the same input, very much like base64_encode will return the same base64 string for the same input

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: ya knitti you are rite that md5 also will give same string on encoding ...i want to know weather there is a library function in php for unique encoding the string and i want decode it also at the same time..

Comment: exactly mr loesomeday...i want to do as you said..

Comment: it will help if you are able to specify what are you trying to achieve in needing that kind of approach.

Comment: i am getting file from user and i want to save it with encoded unique string and i want to pass the name via GET method ...so then i can decode the file name form request and i can use that for my further methods...i wat unique name also since am passing it in url...if there is a function it would be useful for me in many ways ans many methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use base64_encode and prepend a unique identifier like this:

```
$encoded = base64_encode(uniqid().$filename); //$filename is your filename
```

And decode it like this:

```
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
$filename = substr($decoded, 13);
```

This would basically give you an encoded string for the filename that's unique and can be reversed to the filename.

Comment: unique id in the sense rand number up to four digits like that u r saying ?

Comment: `uniqid()` is a php function giving you a 13 digit microtime, this is unique for the server and you can not get collisions like with a random number. The code is actually working as-is.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks a lot.